# Sequence of regenerate data by iCloud transaction logs

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

My app is using core data with iCloud integration.  Let's say, initially, I created 5 objects separately.  So, iCloud received 5 transaction logs.  Next, I delete all objects at once.  So, iCloud received just transaction log(s) for this.  In the final step, I added one object.  So, iCloud received one transaction log.

Now, if I use the same app the first time on anther device, what would be the process of regenerating the data on the new device by iCloud.

A.  Would it only generate the final data base on the last transaction log?

B.  Would it go through all steps in the example above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might do either. The iCloud data starts with a baseline file that represents the initial state. Transactions modify that to get to the current state. Periodically iCloud is supposed to roll transaction logs into an updated baseline file.

In your example, it would do **A** if the transaction logs had been rolled into a new baseline, and it would do **B** if this has not happened yet.

Apple has not documented the policy for rolling transactions into a new baseline.